# Phonegap + jquery mobile + backbutton + pageinit

Tags: cordova

I'm developing a Phonegap (cordova 2.5.0) app with jquery mobile (1.3.1). My question concerning pageinit function behavior after back button pressed. First time when navigating to (for example) statics-page, pageinit fires normally. After that when back button pressed and navigating from menu page to same statics-page again the pageinit does not fires anymore. What would be possible cause of this behavior?

- Jani

  ```
  //PAGEINIT
  $("#staticsPage").live("pageinit", function(){
      alert(staticsPage Init);
      init_statistics();
  });



   document.addEventListener("deviceready", appReady, false);

  //HANDLE BACK BUTTON
  function appReady(){   
      document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
          if($.mobile.activePage.is('#menuPage'))
          {
              e.preventDefault();
              navigator.app.exitApp();
          }

          else if($.mobile.activePage.is('#staticsPage'))
          {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.mobile.changePage($("#menuPage"));
          }
          else 
          {
               navigator.app.backHistory();
          }
      }, false);  

    }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pageinit` event is only fired once the page is loaded into the DOM, so it will only be fired once.

> Triggered on the page being initialized, after initialization occurs

I would use the `pageshow` event. This is fired when you navigate to the page:

> Triggered on the "toPage" after the transition animation has completed.

So, try using this code instead:

```
$('#staticsPage').on('pageshow', function(){
    alert(staticsPage Init);
    init_statistics();
});

document.addEventListener("deviceready", appReady, false);

//HANDLE BACK BUTTON
function appReady()
{   
    document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(e){
        var activePage = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id');

        if(activePage == 'menuPage')
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
        else if(activePage == 'staticsPage')
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.mobile.changePage('#menuPage');
        }
        else 
        {
             navigator.app.backHistory();
        }
    }, false);
}
```

Check [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/) for a list of jQuery Mobile events.